# qml maps show pointer image on each click

Tags: qt, qml, maps

I am having a code like this

```
Map {
    id: map
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: Plugin {
        name: "osm"
    }
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75)
    zoomLevel: 10

    MapQuickItem {
        id: transMarker
        sourceItem: Image {
            id: transImage
            width: 50
            height: 50
            source: "trans.png"
        }
    }
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            var coord = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y));
            transMarker.coordinate = coord;
            console.log(coord.latitude, coord.longitude)
        }
    }
}
```

So on each click now the image moves from one coordinate to next coordinate, i would like to create a copy of the image in each place i click, How can i implement that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a model(like [`ListModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html)) with a [`MapItemView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapitemview.html) that you use as a delegate to the [`MapQuickItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapquickitem.html):

```
ListModel {
    id: markermodel
    dynamicRoles: true
}
Map {
    id: map
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: Plugin {
        name: "osm"
    }
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75)
    zoomLevel: 10
    MapItemView{
        model: markermodel
        delegate: MapQuickItem {
            coordinate: model.position
            sourceItem: Image {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                source: "trans.png"
            }
        }
    }
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            var coord = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y));
            markermodel.append({"position": coord})
        }
    }
}
```